# Compute the product of neighborhood for each cell in a matrix with numpy/scipy

Tags: python, numpy

I'm trying to implement an image processing algorithm which involves computing the product of 4-adjacent neighborhood for each cell. That is, to compute a new matrix Y for X where `y[i, j] = x[i-1, j] * x[i, j-1] * x[i+1, j] * x[i, j+1]`. Out-of-bound neighbors should be ignored.

Now I can only think of this approach: use `scipy.ndimage.filters.correlate` and pass in weights with zeros and one 1 to get four matrices, each containing the neighbor for each cell in a direction, like passing in `weight = [[0, 0, 0], [1, 0, 0], [1, 1]]` and I get `a[i, j] = x[i-1, j]`, and with other weights I can get `b[i, j] =  x[i, j-1]`, `c[i, j] = x[i+1, j]`, `d[i, j] = x[i, j+1]`. Then I use `np.multiply` to compute the product of these four matrices.

However, this approach is a bit too slow, and I can't ignore the boundaries. Is there another way to do it with numpy/scipy so I don't have to resort to for loops?

Comment: If you took logs first, then it would be an addition.

Comment: The 2x2 convolution Discrete Laplace operator would be pretty close once it is addition.  Just need to cancel out central term.  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Discrete_Laplace_operator http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.ndimage.filters.laplace.html

Comment: @Paul Thanks for help, but there might be negative numbers in the matrix, so I can't take logs first.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will need to write out the edges separately, but this does what you are after for the central portion of your array, and is probably noticeably faster than correlation:

```
y = np.empty_like(x)
y[1:-1, 1:-1] = x[1:-1, 1:-1]
y[1:-1, 1:-1] *= x[:-2, 1:-1]
y[1:-1, 1:-1] *= x[2:, 1:-1]
y[1:-1, 1:-1] *= x[1:-1, :-2]
y[1:-1, 1:-1] *= x[1:-1, 2:]
```

Comment: Shouldn't is be `y = numpy.ones_like` and the second line removed?

Answer (score 4):

I think this better matches what you're asking for:

```
import numpy as np

x = np.array([
    [1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
    [6, 7, 8, 9, 1],
    [2, 3, 4, 5, 6],
    [7, 8, 9, 1, 2]
])

y = np.ones_like(x)
y[+1:, :] *= x[:-1, :]
y[:-1, :] *= x[+1:, :]
y[:, +1:] *= x[:, :-1]
y[:, :-1] *= x[:, +1:]

y
#>>> array([[  12,   21,   64,  135,    4],
#>>>        [  14,  288,  756,  160,  270],
#>>>        [ 126,  448, 1080,  216,   10],
#>>>        [  16,  189,   32,   90,    6]])
```

Note that the first `*=` can be an assignment if you need extra speed.